# MS SQL sorting a column with Chinese Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I have a database table which has English and Chinese name in them. I have changed the Chinese name column's collation to Chinese_PRC_CS_AS but it is still not sorting properly.

I would like them to sort according to how the dictionary using (pinyin).

May I know if anybody has done that before?

Comment: Could you give us a small sample of your results that shows your problem, and an example of the sort order that you actually want instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify Chinese_PRC_CS_AS in your select statement

```
select * from yourtable order by columnWithChineseName collate Chinese_PRC_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found the solution at [http://www.blogjava.net/parable-myth/archive/2010/10/12/334525.html][1]. To prevent the link is broken in the future, I will paste the content here. Credit should be given back to the original author.

> sql按拼音排序
>
> select * from user order by name collate Chinese_PRC_CS_AS_KS_WS
>
> 二.排序规则简介：
>
> ```
> 什么叫排序规则呢？ms是这样描述的："在 microsoft sql server 2000 中， 字符串的物理存储由排序规则控制。排序规则指定表示每个字符的位模式以及存 储和比较字符所使用的规则。"
> ```
>
> 在查询分析器内执行下面语句，可以得到sql　server支持的所有排序规则。
>
> select * from ::fn_helpcollations()
>
> 排序规则名称由两部份构成，前半部份是指本排序规则所支持的字符集。 如： chinese_prc_cs_ai_ws 
>   前半部份：指unicode字符集，chinese_prc_指针对大陆简体字unicode的排序规则。 排序规则的后半部份即后缀 含义： 
>   _bin 二进制排序 
>   _ci(cs) 是否区分大小写，ci不区分，cs区分
>   _ai(as) 是否区分重音，ai不区分，as区分　　　
>   _ki(ks) 是否区分假名类型,ki不区分，ks区分　
>       _wi(ws) 是否区分宽度 wi不区分，ws区分
>
> 区分大小写:如果想让比较将大写字母和小写字母视为不等，请选择该选项。
>   区分重音:如果想让比较将重音和非重音字母视为不等，请选择该选项。如果选择该选项，
>            比较还将重音不同的字母视为不等。 区分假名:如果想让比较将片假名和平假名日语音节视为不等，请选择该选项。 区分宽度:如果想让比较将半角字符和全角字符视为不等，请选择该选项
>
> 三.排序规则的应用： sql server提供了大量的windows和sqlserver专用的排序规则，但它的应用往往
>   被开发人员所忽略。其实它在实践中大有用处。
>
> 例1:让表name列的内容按拼音排序：
>
> create table #t(id int,name varchar(20)) insert #t select 1,中 union
>   all select 2,国 union all select 3,人 union all select 4,阿
>
> select * from #t order by name collate chinese_prc_cs_as_ks_ws  drop
>   table #t /*结果： id          name
>   ----------- --------------------  4           阿 2           国 3           人 1           中
>   */
>
> 例2：让表name列的内容按姓氏笔划排序：
>
> create table #t(id int,name varchar(20))
>
> insert #t select 1,三 union all select 2,乙 union all select 3,二 union
>   all select 4,一 union all select 5,十 select * from #t order by name
>   collate chinese_prc_stroke_cs_as_ks_ws  drop table #t /*结果： id
>   name
>   ----------- --------------------  4           一 2           乙 3           二 5           十 1           三
>   */
>
> 四.在实践中排序规则应用的扩展 sql server汉字排序规则可以按拼音、笔划等排序，那么我们如何利用这种功能
>   来处理汉字的一些难题呢？我现在举个例子：
>
> 用排序规则的特性计算汉字笔划
>
> 要计算汉字笔划，我们得先做准备工作，我们知道，windows多国汉字，unicode目前
>   收录汉字共20902个。简体gbk码汉字unicode值从19968开始。
>   首先，我们先用sqlserver方法得到所有汉字，不用字典，我们简单利用sql语句就 可以得到：
>
> select top 20902 code=identity(int,19968,1) into #t from syscolumns
>   a,syscolumns b
>
> 再用以下语句，我们就得到所有汉字，它是按unicode值排序的：
>
> select code,nchar(code) as cnword from #t
>
> 然后，我们用select语句，让它按笔划排序。
>
> select code,nchar(code) as cnword  from #t  order by nchar(code)
>   collate chinese_prc_stroke_cs_as_ks_ws,code
>
> 结果： code        cnword
>
> 本文章出处 http://www.itphome.cn/shujukuyingyong/mssql/2010-01-27/106.html
>
> [1]: http://www.itphome.cn/shujukuyingyong/mssql/2010-01-27/106.html